# Holding view display until response arrives from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my application I've a `UITableViewController` and according to user selections instantiate a new `UIViewController` and sends a request for server via tcp socket.

Before the response arrives from server it already runs "`viewDidLoad`" method of the `UIViewController`.
and in most cases responses hasn't arrived yet.

My questions is: How can I stop the `viewDidLoad` from running until I receive the response and process the data in the `viewDidLoad` method???

and also if possible to make this whole process asynchronous in the way that it doesn't stuck the whole application till response arrives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data processing you are doing in viewDidLoad move it to separate function. When you receive data from server notify view controller or call delegate and after getting notification or delegate call, do your data processing by calling method you separated for data processing.

Comment: I understand you!! you're right.

I do have a delegate which is called when response arrives from server, I need to process the message and set all data of UIViewController!

Thanks!

Another question: what if while waiting for response that user decides to press "back" closes the UIViewController then returns to the UITableViewController and decides to select different UIViewController??

Comment: Only you have to take care of response coming from server. When press back button your view controller will get released. Whatever model you have for data fetching will try to call delegate after getting response and wil crash there as view controller is released. In model you have to check if delegate exists before calling any delegate method.

Comment: As far as I can tell, everytime I instantiate a new UIViewController I set it as a delegate for processing the response. so I guess UIViewController_X might receive a message intended to be sent to UIViewController_Y and I have to ignore it in X. correct?

Comment: Is your data fetching model is shared instance or you create new each time you create view controller?

Comment: shared. 

I have a socket class that resides in my AppDelagate class as a property. and from the UITableViewController I access it to set a delegate for responses and for firing requests to server.

Is that bad??

Comment: Then you need to cancel all requests sent from view controller on back button action. And you can create singleton class of Socket class instead of creating property in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion first, you need to select a row from the table & then call your `UIViewController` & in this class, you can write one separate method like

> ```
>     -(void)GetData{}
> ```

then call it in background thread-like

> ```
>     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(GetData) withObject:nil];
> ```

and this process of call service & get data work in the background & when its response comes from the server you do some stuff like fill data in the view or display it.

by doing this your app will not still until your response comes.

Comment: I need somehow to pass GetData to my socket class so when response arrive it call GetData with response??

Comment: yes, Shvalb you can call GetData From your shocket class by adding delegate method on that class & by this u can call current viewcontroller class method -(void)GetData;